# What was the projected Dark Mark made up of in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

[image]

The Dark Mark, as seen above, was projected whenever <strike>Voldemort</strike> (He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named) touched the Dark Mark tattoo on his arm. What evidence is there to support what material this projection was made up of? Light? Matter?

Comment: It was made of magic!

Comment: It was digitally made - VFX. It wasn't real...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Dark Mark appears to be composed of stars and smoke:

> For a split second, Harry thought it was another leprechaun formation. Then he realised that it was a colossal skull, composed of what looked like emerald stars, with a serpent protruding from its mouth like a tongue. As they watched, it rose higher and higher, blazing in a haze of greenish smoke, etched against the black sky like a new constellation.
>   *Goblet of Fire* - page 116 - UK - chapter 9, *The Dark Mark*

and:

> The Dark Mark was glittering directly above the Astronomy Tower, the highest of the castle.
>   *Half-Blood Prince* - page 544 - UK - chapter 27, *The Lightning Struck Tower*

If the Dark Mark is indeed made from stars, then the matter composing it would be (progressively) plasma, hydrogen, helium, heavier elements, and possibly degenerate matter. [STAR - WIKIPEDIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star). The luminosity from the stars is what makes the Dark Mark glow. As for smoke, the Wiki defines it as "a collection of airborne solid and liquid particulates and gases as the result of combustion."

The Dark Mark is actually conjured by an incantation -- Morsmordre -- and not by Voldemort touching the Dark Mark on his forearm (when Voldemort touches his Dark Mark, or a Death Eater's mark, it summons all the Death Eaters to his presence). Morsmordre requires a wand and only Death Eaters know how to conjure it. The Dark Mark in both *Goblet of Fire* (from where your picture is from) the book and the movie was conjured by Barty Crouch Jr. In the movie *Half-Blood Prince*, Bellatrix Lestrange conjures the Dark Mark after Dumbledore is killed; in the book the Death Eater who conjures the Dark Mark *before* Dumbledore is killed is not named.

Comment: It'a bit of a logical leap from "what looked like emerald stars" to hydrogen and helium.

Comment: Not so. The book says they formed a new constellation. Why wouldn't they mean stars in the literal sense? In a world where spells can defy gravity, paintings are sentient, and luck can be ingested, I don't think a low hanging hydrogen field is an unrealistic or illogical interpretation.

Comment: "_like_ a new constellation." In the quote from GoF, nothing says the mark is actually made of stars or actually does form a constellation; only that that is how it appears to Harry, and since to us Earthlings a star appears as nothing but a point of light, all it's saying is that the Dark Mark is an arrangement of emerald-colored points of light. Besides, a small blob of hydrogen couldn't naturally sustain nuclear fusion (actual stars are _huge_), and even if it could, it wouldn't be green. I'm sure there is some more efficient magical method of making green glowing things than with hydrogen.

Comment: You know, I may very well be wrong. I gave an answer based *on what canon says* with information along those lines. I don't think it's entirely fair to judge Wizarding magic by Muggle standards. Wizards can squeeze through interstitial space (Apparition), become invisible, blow up their aunt without killing her, Transfigure themselves into an object 10x smaller than themselves without losing any mass, and turn into animals at will. Again, I'm not saying my answer is perfect or "right," but it is a *Harry Potter* question, and *Harry Potter* is not real, and it doesn't abide by Muggle rules.

Comment: Anyone trying to apply scientific principles to Harry Potter doesn't understand the point of Harry Potter. It's Magic. You don't need sustained nuclear fusion in Magic. Slytherincess's answer takes what little information is given in the books, and summarizes it nicely. If you want a *scientific explanation for Morsmordre*, maybe you should relax a little bit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm with @David Zaslavsy here. "looked like" is not there by accident - if it **was** indeed composed of stars, the text would not have had those 2 words.

Comment: Well, like I said, I could be wrong, but I based my answer off canon. If implicit textual verification is your standard, then that means Harry is a Horcrux (he wasn't), the Sorting Hat couldn't sense the part of Voldemort's soul in Harry (it could), and that wands are in no way sentient (they are quasi-sentient). My point: stars are *possible*.

Comment: Since the smallest possible star capable of being a star is over 100 000 km wide with a surface temperature of 1700 C, we know that it was absolutely not composed of stars. I speculate that ol' Voldy emptied a glow tube and some glitter glue into the sky.